# In hdp 2.3.4.7-4, where two applications appear when using REST API to submit jobs

Tags: javascript, json, rest, hadoop

I'm using Hadoop in my university project and I'm building an application for demonstration purposes. I've decided to use the REST API because I'll be demoing remotely. 
I'm trying to get the 'wordcount' example to run using a JSON query and it seems to work fine.

My question is why does Hadoop start two applications, see image:

[image]

I submitted application: "application_1427474834422_0076" and then another starts. Is this normal behaviour? what'more. progress bar has not been moving at 18.2% and failure eventually

Here is the JSON query I used

```js
{
  "application-id": "application_1471255114270_0082",
  "application-name": "wordcount",
  "am-container-spec": {
    "local-resources": {
      "entry": [{
        "key": "hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar",
        "value": {
          "resource": "hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/MapReduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar",
          "type": "FILE",
          "visibility": "APPLICATION",
          "size": "273458",
          "timestamp": "1470646121574"
        }
      }]
    },
    "commands": {
      "command": "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java -Xmx10m org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar wordcount hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/demo.txt hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/output  1>/tmp/mrtest.stdout 2>/tmp/mrtest.stderr"
    },
    "environment": {
      "entry": [{
        "key": "CLASSPATH",
        "value": "/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/etc/hadoop<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-mapreduce/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-hdfs/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-yarn/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-yarn/lib/*<CPS>/lib/*"
      }]
    }
  },
  "unmanaged-AM": "false",
  "max-app-attempts": "2",
  "resource": {
    "memory": "1024",
    "vCores": "1"
  },
  "application-type": "MAPREDUCE",
  "keep-containers-across-application-attempts": "false"
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Note that you have `wordcount` and `word count`. By looking at how these two terms occur in your code you should be able to understand what the two applications are.

Comment: Usually, you submit a job and then YARN generates the job ID. But here you seem to force a job ID *(an existing ID??)* -- and YARN generates another ID for the new job anyway.

Comment: Or maybe your "job" only starts a dummy MapReduce job with just a single mapper *(similar to an Oozie "launcher")* that executes the `RunJar` command -- something you usually do on your command line -- then the `RunJar` starts the actual MapReduce job (with a distinct ID).

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with that REST API...

Answer (score 0):

I have seen multiple applications get started, for instance with pig jobs, or oozie jobs. As such it does not strike me as odd.

However, there is something strange in your screenshot: Your application seems to have status accepted (rather than running). As such it is surprising that is has any progress at all, as one would typically expect the progress to build after the job starts running.

My advice: Just debug the applications that fail, without worrying about the fact that 2 are created at the same time.

---

Bit out of scope for this question, but if you notice that it gets stuck at 'accepted' one would typically check whether there is sufficient capacity available to start new work. (Looking at memory and container count).

Comment: thanks kindly. i have got something that corrected my mistakes yes, but there's still some confusion, it's very obvious that only the submission of a job, why started twice applications? so how can i looking at memory and container count , I would greatly appreciate

Comment: the important point is two job,I keep getting two applications with consequent numbers: one under the user specified in request ("me",such dr.who), and one - under "yarn" user. so i'm strongly confused,thanks

Comment: @zd.H In the query it once mentions `wordcount` but never `word count`, as such this cannot be all relevant code. If you find the code that contains `word count` you will probably gain more understanding in what is going on.

Comment: Isn't this time sleeping? ok , i will try it , thank for your time deeply, Just as an old Chiness saying goes well 遇见你是我的缘，thank you very much